# How to solve $a\sqrt{x}\pm b\sqrt{y}=c\sqrt{z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}>1$

How do I prove if $x,y,z$ are square-free integers and: $$a\sqrt{x}\pm b\sqrt{y}=c\sqrt{z}$$

Then $\gcd(x,y,z)>1$?

I know for some of you it may be simple. As for me, it's not that trivial. Please any hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Minor exception if $x=y=z=1$.

Comment: 1 is not square free btw.

Comment: That is a matter of definition. The definition I have always used includes $1$ among the square-frees. My preferred definition is not idiosyncratic, [please see Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)

Answer (score 3):

Square the whole expression. You get that
$$
a^2x\pm b^2y+2ab\sqrt{xy}=c^2z
$$
or in other words, that $xy$ is a perfect square (otherwise the left-hand side wouldn't be an integer).

That means, since $x$ and $y$ are both square-free, that $x=y$. The above equation then says that
$$
(a\pm b)^2x=c^2z
$$
And again, by square-free-ness, we must have $x=z$. Therefore the full relation is that $x=y=z$. What you wanted to prove follows as long as $1$ isn't considered square-free.

Comment: ,I don't think that we must have $x=y$ for $xy$ to be a a perfect square. For instance, $x=2$ and $y=8$ would yield $xy=16={4}^2$

Comment: @NumThcurious but $8$ isn't square-free, it contains a factor $4=2^2$.